# Tailwind not changing styles in my React JS app

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I've used Tailwind CSS before, but it's not working now for some reason.

It's resetting all the basic styles as it should, but when I add new styles it's not updating.

Here is the code:

**tailwind.config.js:**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**index.css:**

```js
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**package.json:**

```js
 "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1"
  }
```

here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "social-media-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "firebase": "^9.10.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "tailwind-scrollbar-hide": "^1.1.7",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.11",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```

project structure:
[image: here is the project structure]

Comment: Hi, can you please provide your project's file structure? I guess, the problem is wrong content regex in your tailwind config.

Comment: And can you add your full `package.json` file?

Comment: @fpetrakov I add the file you asked for